# How to select the number of occurency of some data each week till today

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select the number of data recorded each week from table. The issue I am having is that, the query display result up to 24 June but today is 28 June. Any idea how to make it reach the date when the query has been executed.
This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(date) AS weekno,
           COUNT(1) AS total_num_of_occurence, 
           SUBDATE(date, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(date) DAY) AS date_of_week 
    FROM table

GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(date)
```

Thanks

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to select data from the database that does not exist within the database?

Comment: @Strawberry Data already exists in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but is this by chance the answer...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/013e3/1

Comment: I changed the min to max and got what I was looking for. Great thanks